# Torchvision transforms.toPILImage() TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library, conda, torchvision

From Anaconda
pillow      -> 7.00
torchvision -> 0.5.0

I installed the latest Anaconda for Linux( Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh) today and I run the following commands,

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
conda activate py36
conda install -c pytorch torchvision
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
conda install -c conda-forge python-pptx
conda install -c conda-forge labelme
conda install -c conda-forge tensorboardx
conda install -c anaconda ipywidgets
conda install -c conda-forge ipyvolume
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 
conda install -c anaconda pytables

jupyter-notebook
```

Running the same exact code that I am running for months now,

[image: trusted code]

```
# visualize a single example to verify that it is correct
( img, patch_mask, patch_mask_weight, fname) = dataset[ "train"][ 70]
```

I am getting the following error,

[image: error]

How could this be resolved? Please let me know if more code is needed.

**UPDATE I**

The code shown applies a series of transformation to two RGB images and a label image having unique values of 0, 1, 2 for background, foreground and regions to be ignored during deep learning training respectively. The output below comes from added `print` statements in to the code shown in the error trace shown above.

[image: Output]

It looks that for the first RGB image everything works fine whereas for the label image there's a problem. Specifically, the rotation transformation is the problematic one where the `color` attribute has a tuple as a value. The same attribute in the ToPILImage transform though, has a value of a single integer.

Thanks

Comment: While I have not used torchvision before, from the call stack I suspect you need to provide a default fill color to the transformations. This could be a torchvision bug, where the default fill color value is a 3-tuple, but should be an integer (or something else, perhaps determined by the image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes when transform `RandomRotation` is invoked and a new instance of `Image` class is created. Particularly,  function `core.fill()` at line 2544 `return im._new( core.fill(mode, size, color))` in function `new`, in file `anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py` is the source of 'evil'.

`core` is the alias of file `anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` when imported as `from . import _imaging as core` at line 69 in the same file( Image.py).

Function `core.fill(mode, size, color))` depending on the `mode` has different expectations about `color`. `color` is always a 3 - tuple, lines 726 - 727 in file `anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py`, function `rotate` i.e. `RandomRotation` transform.

If `mode == RGB` everything is fine. If `mode == L` then `TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)` is raised. If `mode == F`, `TypeError: must be real number, not tuple` is raised. I found that given my images under transformation.

For `mode in [ 'L', 'F']`, parameter `color` needs to be a single integer. For other `mode`s that might be also true.

Thus, I solved my problem by updating the code as,

```
if mode in [ 'L', 'F'] and isinstance( color, tuple):
     color = color[ 0]

return im._new( core.fill(mode, size, color))
```

in file `anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py`, function `new`.

This change is closest to the problem. However, since, `new` appears to be used for every transformation, it might be better changing the code somewhere else so that the change has the minimum impact possible to the rest of the code.